# Why is there no memory translation on the heap?

Tags: operating-system, heap-memory

I'm trying to understand why there is no compaction on the heap. Why is no memory translation possible, if the data is allocated by the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the only translation is translating virtual addresses that the program uses into physical addresses that the hardware uses.

Compacting the heap in virtual memory would involve changing the virtual addresses that a program uses, which is expensive or impossible unless all the overhead already exists for other reasons (some approaches to garbage collection).

Fortunately the way the translation (of virtual addresses into physical addresses) works means that you can have unused gaps in virtual memory (or in the heap) that don't cost anything; so for larger gaps (above the system's page size) there isn't much to gain from compacting the heap. Smaller gaps are more likely to be too small to care about (you really don't want to move 1234 MiB of data just to get rid of a little 123 byte gap).